# How do I access the Linksys E2000 wireless router setup page

Tags: wireless-networking, router, setup, administration

I'm trying to access & configure my wireless router's options.

The wireless router is a [Linksys E2000](http://homestore.cisco.com/en-us/Routers/Linksys-E2000-Advanced-Wirelessn-router_stcVVproductId97826161VVcatId551966VVviewprod.htm) and the default gateway's IP address is 192.168.33.1

I've gotten into the router setup by simply typing this address into Internet Explorer and using the particular router's default username and password.  The problem is that when I enter this IP address (192.168.33.1) into Internet Explorer, nothing happens... it is just a blank white screen with.  There are no error messages or anything for that matter.

Also, after I connect to the router and enter a URL, I am redirected to [this](http://cochinoman.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/ciscoguest.jpg) page.  I then need to enter a password on that screen first in order to access any other website.

What do I need to do to access the setup page for the [Linksys E2000](http://homestore.cisco.com/en-us/Routers/Linksys-E2000-Advanced-Wirelessn-router_stcVVproductId97826161VVcatId551966VVviewprod.htm) wireless router?

I couldn't find any helpful documentation on the internet and I was hoping someone on this site would know how to resolve this situation.

The only constraint I have is that I must connect to the router via WiFi.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: How are you connected to the router? Did you join its wireless network? Or did you connect to it with a wire? Did you confirm that your machine was assigned an IP address by the router?

Comment: Wireless. I am able to access the router and use the internet.  My assigned address is 192.168.33.100 so I know the DHCP is giving me permission and I know that I'm properly connected

Comment: The router has the ability to disable admin from wireless clients. Most likely, this is enabled. (Double check that your default gateway is 192.168.33.1, just in case the router is 192.168.33.2 or something like that.) Try from a wired station if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check to see that you dont have two networks based on the image it looks like you are connecting the a guest network on the router rather than the main network this may be causing your problem.

I have a Netgear router that has a guest network set up and I can't access the admin page from the guest network.